# Cant make the loop work properly

Tags: c++

The code below is supposed to let me choose an option from the menu and then display the appropriate line from the switch statement. It only works when I choose option 'g'. If I choose 'c', it displays the `cout` line but then it skips the loop and the program exits. What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;
enum {c='c', p='p', t='t', g='g'}; // 0-3

int main(){
    cout
            << "Elija una opcion del menu:" << endl
            << "c) carnivoros" << endl
            << "p) pianista" << endl
            << "t) Arbol" << endl
            << "g) Juegos" << endl;
    char eleccion;
    cin.get(eleccion);

    while (eleccion >= c && eleccion <= g){
            switch (eleccion)
            {
            case 'c' : cout << "Te gusta la carne e!\n"; break;
            case 'p' : cout << "Sos pianista?\n"; break;
            case 't' : cout << "Naturista!\n"; break;
            case 'g' : cout << "Vicio!\n"; break;  
            }
            cout
                    << "Elija una opcion del menu:" << endl;
            cin.get(eleccion);             
    }
_getche();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: @DigitalNinja: That's not relevant.

Comment: I just getting started, what typos ?

Comment: "and" "omly" "de" "dunno" "whats" - doesn't matter that your first language is; it just takes a few moments of effort to check your writing. If you can get into this habit with written language, then you will also be in that habit for computer languages, and you will be a better programmer!

Comment: Anyway, this is asked all the time. Your newline is left in the buffer.

Comment: What is that close vote Lightning? This question is in no way similar to that. This is failing because the chars in the enum are converted to int.

Comment: (eleccion >= c && eleccion <= g)

This line breaks it.

    enum {c='c', p='p', t='t', g='g'}; // 0-3

The enum won't be c=0 ... g=3, but it will be c = 99, p = 112, t = 116, g = 103 (ASCII)

Thus, your if will turn into:
  
    (eleccion >= 99 && eleccion <= 103)

And 112 and 116 clearly don't pass that condition.

Comment: There's the reason it's failing, not cause of the newline.

Comment: @LightningRacisinObrit: It's not exactly a dup of the post you linked. Please don't mark it as such. Yes, OP's English isn't great, but it's not hard to understand it. If you had an issue with the amount of debugging OP did or the quality of their code,  that I'd understand.

Comment: @LordZsolt Ah balls well that is a problem with it, yes. But there is also a buffer problem.

Comment: So, the problem is with the while conditional, the program works if I dont assign 'characters' to the 'enum', but it works only reading number 0 trough 3(the enum lenght) and I want the user to input the letter of choice, not the number...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(eleccion >= c && eleccion <= g)
```

This line breaks it.

```
enum {c='c', p='p', t='t', g='g'}; // 0-3
```

The enum won't be c=0 ... g=3, but it will be c = 99, p = 112, t = 116, g = 103,

Thus, your if will turn into:

```
(eleccion >= 99 && eleccion <= 103)
```

And 112 and 116 clearly don't pass that condition.

---

Also as [LightningRacisinOrbit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560648/lightning-racis-in-obrit) pointed it out, you'll have a problem with the newline remaining in the buffer as well. A solution to it would be to use `cin >> eleccion` as [MikeMB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2881849/mikemb) suggested.

---

You could change the condition in the if statement to

```
(eleccion >= c && eleccion <= t)
```

However it's still very ugly. Probably this would be the best:

```
(eleccion == c || eleccion == g || eleccion == p || eleccion == t)
```

Comment: You can have a +1 because you're the only person to get it right. Still, this answer could be improved!

Comment: Ok its working, thanks a lot, taking Lighting Racis Orbit chirtics too =)

Comment: I tried but lady Lighting took off my point giving status by downvoting my question, from me. I love her anyway. Cheers

Comment: Heh? You can accept answers (clicking on the tick) with 0 rep as far as I know.

Comment: =0, I tought not, my selfsteem is on the floor , hehe =/

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems in your code:

1. `cin.get(eleccion);` doesn't clear the new line character from the input stream, so right the next time `cin.get` is called, it will read the newline character, which is outside the range you specified and it will terminate the loop. Use `cin >> eleccion;` instead to fix that.
2. As you assign ASCII letters to your enum, the bigges enum is NOT `g` but `t`, so your loop header should look like this:

   ```
   while (  c <= eleccion && eleccion <= t){
   ```

This version still has the drawback, that your loop continues if you enter any char between `c` and `t` (which si most of the alphabet) even if it is not a valid selection. For that reason I'd change the program as follows:

```
using namespace std;
//enums are not needed
int main(){
    cout << "Opciones:" << endl
        << "c) carnivoros" << endl
        << "p) pianista" << endl
        << "t) Arbol" << endl
        << "g) Juegos" << endl;


    bool rightChar = true;

    while (rightChar){
        cout << "Elija una opcion del menu:" << endl;

        char eleccion;
        cin >> eleccion;
        switch (eleccion)
        {
            case 'c': cout << "Te gusta la carne e!\n"; break;
            case 'p': cout << "Sos pianista?\n"; break;
            case 't': cout << "Naturista!\n"; break;
            case 'g': cout << "Vicio!\n"; break;
            default: rightChar = false;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```